# Unknown Format exception with text/plain,text/html; Accept header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mime-types, ruby-on-rails-4.1

The accept header `"Accept: text/plain,text/html;"` works for sites like http://nginx.org. However when I run it locally against my Rails 4.1 app

```
curl -v -H "Accept: text/plain,text/html;" localhost:3000/
```

on a html responding homepage, I get a 500 error page for an  `ActionController::UnknownFormat` execption.

When I curl

```
curl -v -H "Accept: text/plain,text/html" localhost:3000
```

everything works fine (notice the missing `;`)

How can I also  make it work for `Accept: text/plain,text/html;` case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's malformed according to RFC 7231 and shouldn't work. nginx.org turns back `200 OK` even for obviously malformed MIME types.

See also https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21749